# Are there vampires in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, vampire

Are there vampires in Star Wars?

(*I was prompted to ask by this [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7705/why-wasnt-han-solo-suspicious-when-he-first-dove-into-the-asteroid-cave/7711#7711)*)

Comment: the premise for your question is very strange and I am guessing is the reason for the downvote. The question has merit, as shown by the answer, but you don't need the quote from the other question.

Comment: @JustinC - Edited to give less prominence for the reason why the question arose, better?

Comment: How about werewolves?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes. They are the species called Anzati.

A very good writeup about them can be found here:

http://scifi.about.com/od/starwarscharacters/a/SWAR_anzati.htm

> The Anzati are an alien race in the Star Wars universe probably inspired by vampires. These mysterious aliens have many characteristics in common with vampires: they hunger for the life force of other beings, subdue their victims with mind control, live for millennia, are incredibly fast and strong, and have no pulse.

Curiously enough, they appear to be even G-canon (well... may be... I will ask that as a separate question)!

> The first Anzati in Star Wars canon was Dannik Jerriko, a bounty hunter who appeared in the Cantina Scene in Episode IV: A New Hope. His backstory is explored in the short story "Soup's On: The Pipe Smoker's Tale," by Jennifer Roberson, which appears in the short story collection Tales from the Mos Eisley Cantina (Bantam Spectra, 1995).

Comment: G-canon-level vampires... wow.

Comment: @Griwes - simply because someone has identified an unnamed background character as being 'a vampire' doesn't make it G-Canon.

Answer (score 3):

### Vampires (of varying descriptions) appear throughout the Star Wars canon but NOT in the film canon, except through EU additions.

Various kinds include;

### Energy Vampires

These are found in the [Star Wars : Clone Wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Energy_vampire) canon;

> Energy vampires were creatures who drained the life forces of others,
>   by way of biting their enemies in order to feed. They had retractable
>   serrated claws, elongated teeth, accelerated senses, and enhanced
>   strength and speed. They were able to drain beings of energy to feed
>   as well as turning these beings into mindless zombies;

[image: Countess Rajine Vampire]

### Anzati

These are [intially](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anzat) mentioned in Star Wars : TOR

> The Anzati (singular: Anzat) were a dangerous and mysterious
>   Force-sensitive near-Human species with two tentacle-like proboscises
>   that curled out and extended from their cheeks, with which the Anzati
>   were able to feed upon the brains of their prey. With the tentacles
>   retracted into seams along each side of their nose, Anzati were
>   indistinguishable from any other humanoid species in the galaxy.

[image]

### Force Vampire

This individual is [mentioned](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_Vampire) in the source book for Star Wars : The Roleplaying Game

> The Force Vampire, formerly known as Jedi Knight Tel Angor, was the
>   result of the Order of the Silver Jedi's experiments into creating a
>   living symbol of the light side of the Force. Unfortunately for the
>   Order, the experiments had the exact opposite effect; rather than
>   Angor drawing on the Force to bolster his abilities, the dark side
>   corrupted him completely, turning him into a hideous creature that fed
>   on the Force itself, and indeed needed it to survive. Angor ceased to
>   be himself, and became the Force Vampire.

Comment: I think ultimately the Anzati are the closest thing to what we think of as actual vampires. Especially to Quinlan Vos - he was terrified of them.